# making a weight and height converter, How do I switch between height and weight conversion using buttons?

Tags: javascript

I'm made a simple javascript weight converter, I want to take it further by adding height conversion too, I want the user to be able to click the weight button and convert weight or/then click the height button and convert height. the weight part is working well but the switch to heigh is giving me problems. I've Been trying to fix this for a week now. here is a link to my code https://codepen.io/blessing94/pen/JjXdvbo
thanks for the help!

here is the js code.

```
    //hides weight cards
    document.getElementById('ozCard').style.display = 'none'; 
    document.getElementById('lbsCard').style.display = 'none'; 
    document.getElementById('kgCard').style.display = 'none'; 
    // hides height cards
    document.getElementById('cmCard').style.display = 'none'; 
    document.getElementById('mtCard').style.display = 'none'; 
    document.getElementById('ftCard').style.display = 'none'; 
    //hides the Radios
    document.getElementById('weightRadios').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('heightRadios').style.display = 'none';

    //adds event listener for weight radio buttons
    var inputCheck = document.querySelector('.inputCheck');
    for(var i=0; i<inputCheck; i++){
    inputCheck[i].addEventListener('change', convertWeight, false);
    }
    //adds event listener for height radios
    var inputChecked = document.querySelector('.inputChecked');
    for(var j=0; j<inputCheck; j++){
    inputChecked[j].addEventListener('input', convertHeight, false);
    }

    //function to make weight radios visible
    function weightFunction(){
    var weightRadios = document.getElementById('weightRadios');
    if (weightRadios.style.display === 'none' )
    {   weightRadios.style.display = 'inline';
        heightRadios.style.display = 'none';
       
    } else {
        weightRadios.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
    //function to make height radios visible
    function heightFunction(){
      var heightRadios = document.getElementById('heightRadios' );
      if (heightRadios.style.display === 'none') {
        heightRadios.style.display = 'inline';
        weightRadios.style.display = 'none';
        
      } else {
        heightRadios.style.display = 'none';
    }
    }

    //adds event listener for the mass input
    document.getElementById('massInput').addEventListener
    ('input', convertWeight, false);
   
    //weight function
    function convertWeight(){
  
    //Declaring mass var for the input
    var mass = document.getElementById('massInput').value;

    //checking what radio is checked
    //converting to kg in all cases
    if(document.getElementById('kgChecked').checked ==true){
        var kg = mass;
      }else if(document.getElementById('lbsChecked').checked ==true){
            var kg = mass * 0.45359237;
      }else if(document.getElementById('ozChecked').checked ==true){
                var kg = mass * 0.0283495231;
    }
    //declaring each card
    var kgCard = document.getElementById("kgCard");
    var lbsCard = document.getElementById("lbsCard");
    var ozCard = document.getElementById("ozCard");
    var cmCard = document.getElementById("cmCard");
    var mtCard = document.getElementById("mtCard");
    var ftCard = document.getElementById("ftCard");
   
    //Making unwanted cards disapear 
    if(document.getElementById('kgChecked').checked ==true)
    {
        kgCard.style.display = ('none')
        cmCard.style.display = ('none')
        mtCard.style.display = ('none')
        ftCard.style.display = ('none')
        lbsCard.style.display = ('inline')
        ozCard.style.display = ('inline')
        
    }else{
        kgCard.style.display = ('inline')
        }

    if(document.getElementById('lbsChecked').checked ==true){
        lbsCard.style.display = ('none')
        cmCard.style.display = ('none')
        mtCard.style.display = ('none')
        ftCard.style.display = ('none')
        kgCard.style.display = ('inline')
        ozCard.style.display = ('inline')
    }else{
        lbsCard.style.display = ('inline')
    }

    if(document.getElementById('ozChecked').checked ==true){
        ozCard.style.display = ('none')
        cmCard.style.display = ('none')
        mtCard.style.display = ('none')
        ftCard.style.display = ('none')
        kgCard.style.display = ('inline')
        lbsCard.style.display = ('inline')
    }else{
        ozCard.style.display = ('inline')
    }
     //converting to other units from kg
    // rounding to 3 decimals using math.round
    document.getElementById('kgOutput').innerHTML = 
    numberWithSpaces(Math.round(kg*1000)/1000);

    document.getElementById('lbsOutput').innerHTML = 
    numberWithSpaces(Math.round(kg* 2.20462262 * 1000)/1000);

    document.getElementById('ozOutput').innerHTML = 
    numberWithSpaces(Math.round(kg * 35.2739619 * 1000)/1000);
    }
    document.getElementById('massInput').addEventListener
    ('input', convertHeight, false);

    //function for height convertion
    function convertHeight(){
  
    var massInput = document.getElementById('massInput').value;
    
    //checking what radio is checked and converting to cm in all cases
    if(document.getElementById('cmChecked').checked ==true){
        var cm = massInput;
      }else if(document.getElementById('mtChecked').checked ==true){
            var cm = massInput * 0.45359237;
      }else if(document.getElementById('ftChecked').checked ==true){
                var cm = massInput * 0.0283495231;
    }
  
    // hiding un wanted cards
    if(document.getElementById('cmChecked').checked ==true)
    {
        kgCard.style.display = ('none')
        cmCard.style.display = ('none')
        lbsCard.style.display = ('none')
        ozCard.style.display = ('none')
        ftCard.style.display = ('inline')
        mtCard.style.display = ('inline')
        
    }else{
        cmCard.style.display = ('inline')
        
    }
    
    if(document.getElementById('mtChecked').checked ==true){
        lbsCard.style.display = ('none')
        kgCard.style.display = ('none')
        mtCard.style.display = ('none')
        ozCard.style.display = ('none')
        cmCard.style.display = ('inline')
        ftCard.style.display = ('inline')
        
    }else{
        mtCard.style.display = ('inline')
    }
    
    if(document.getElementById('ftChecked').checked ==true){
        ftCard.style.display = ('none')
        ozCard.style.display = ('none')
        lbsCard.style.display = ('none')
        kgCard.style.display = ('none')
        mtCard.style.display = ('inline')
        cmCard.style.display = ('inline')
    }else{
        ftCard.style.display = ('inline')
    }
  
    // height output
    document.getElementById('cmOutput').innerHTML = 
    numberWithSpaces(Math.round(cm*1000)/1000);

    document.getElementById('mtOutput').innerHTML = 
    numberWithSpaces(Math.round(cm* 2.20462262 * 1000)/1000);

    document.getElementById('ftOutput').innerHTML = 
    numberWithSpaces(Math.round(cm * 35.2739619 * 1000)/1000);

   }
    //Seperate thousands by spaces
    function numberWithSpaces(x) {
        return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had some console error regarding checked element `mtChecked` - There is no element in your `mtChecked` - Its `metersChecked` - Your code is all working now below.

Also, your JS code needs a-lot `optimisation` and can be `reduced` to say around less then `100` lines.

**Live Working Demo**

```js
//hides weight cards
document.getElementById('ozCard').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('lbsCard').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('kgCard').style.display = 'none';
// hides height cards
document.getElementById('cmCard').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('mtCard').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('ftCard').style.display = 'none';
//hides the Radios
document.getElementById('weightRadios').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('heightRadios').style.display = 'none';

//adds event listener for weight radio buttons
var inputCheck = document.querySelector('.inputCheck');
for (var i = 0; i < inputCheck; i++) {
  inputCheck[i].addEventListener('change', convertWeight, false);
}
//adds event listener for height radios
var inputChecked = document.querySelector('.inputChecked');
for (var j = 0; j < inputCheck; j++) {
  inputChecked[j].addEventListener('input', convertHeight, false);
}

//function to make weight radios visible
function weightFunction() {
  var weightRadios = document.getElementById('weightRadios');
  if (weightRadios.style.display === 'none') {
    weightRadios.style.display = 'inline';
    heightRadios.style.display = 'none';

  } else {
    weightRadios.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
//function to make height radios visible
function heightFunction() {
  var heightRadios = document.getElementById('heightRadios');
  if (heightRadios.style.display === 'none') {
    heightRadios.style.display = 'inline';
    weightRadios.style.display = 'none';

  } else {
    heightRadios.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

//adds event listener for the mass input
document.getElementById('massInput').addEventListener('input', convertWeight, false);

//weight function
function convertWeight() {

  //Declaring mass var for the input
  var mass = document.getElementById('massInput').value;

  //checking what radio is checked
  //converting to kg in all cases
  if (document.getElementById('kgChecked').checked == true) {
    var kg = mass;
  } else if (document.getElementById('lbsChecked').checked == true) {
    var kg = mass * 0.45359237;
  } else if (document.getElementById('ozChecked').checked == true) {
    var kg = mass * 0.0283495231;
  }
  //declaring each card
  var kgCard = document.getElementById("kgCard");
  var lbsCard = document.getElementById("lbsCard");
  var ozCard = document.getElementById("ozCard");
  var cmCard = document.getElementById("cmCard");
  var mtCard = document.getElementById("mtCard");
  var ftCard = document.getElementById("ftCard");

  //Making unwanted cards disapear 
  if (document.getElementById('kgChecked').checked == true) {
    kgCard.style.display = ('none')
    cmCard.style.display = ('none')
    mtCard.style.display = ('none')
    ftCard.style.display = ('none')
    lbsCard.style.display = ('inline')
    ozCard.style.display = ('inline')
  } else {
    kgCard.style.display = ('inline')
  }

  if (document.getElementById('lbsChecked').checked == true) {
    lbsCard.style.display = ('none')
    cmCard.style.display = ('none')
    mtCard.style.display = ('none')
    ftCard.style.display = ('none')
    kgCard.style.display = ('inline')
    ozCard.style.display = ('inline')
  } else {
    lbsCard.style.display = ('inline')
  }

  if (document.getElementById('ozChecked').checked == true) {
    ozCard.style.display = ('none')
    cmCard.style.display = ('none')
    mtCard.style.display = ('none')
    ftCard.style.display = ('none')
    kgCard.style.display = ('inline')
    lbsCard.style.display = ('inline')
  } else {
    ozCard.style.display = ('inline')
  }
  //converting to other units from kg
  // rounding to 3 decimals using math.round
  document.getElementById('kgOutput').innerHTML =
    numberWithSpaces(Math.round(kg * 1000) / 1000);

  document.getElementById('lbsOutput').innerHTML =
    numberWithSpaces(Math.round(kg * 2.20462262 * 1000) / 1000);

  document.getElementById('ozOutput').innerHTML =
    numberWithSpaces(Math.round(kg * 35.2739619 * 1000) / 1000);
}
document.getElementById('massInput').addEventListener('input', convertHeight, false);

//function for height convertion
function convertHeight() {

  var massInput = document.getElementById('massInput').value;

  //checking what radio is checked and converting to cm in all cases
  if (document.getElementById('cmChecked').checked == true) {
    var cm = massInput;
  } else if (document.getElementById('metersChecked').checked == true) {
    var cm = massInput * 0.45359237;
  } else if (document.getElementById('ftChecked').checked == true) {
    var cm = massInput * 0.0283495231;
  }

  // hiding un wanted cards
  if (document.getElementById('cmChecked').checked == true) {
    kgCard.style.display = ('none')
    cmCard.style.display = ('none')
    lbsCard.style.display = ('none')
    ozCard.style.display = ('none')
    ftCard.style.display = ('inline')
    mtCard.style.display = ('inline')

  } else {
    cmCard.style.display = ('inline')

  }

  if (document.getElementById('metersChecked').checked == true) {
    lbsCard.style.display = ('none')
    kgCard.style.display = ('none')
    mtCard.style.display = ('none')
    ozCard.style.display = ('none')
    cmCard.style.display = ('inline')
    ftCard.style.display = ('inline')

  } else {
    mtCard.style.display = ('inline')
  }

  if (document.getElementById('ftChecked').checked == true) {
    ftCard.style.display = ('none')
    ozCard.style.display = ('none')
    lbsCard.style.display = ('none')
    kgCard.style.display = ('none')
    mtCard.style.display = ('inline')
    cmCard.style.display = ('inline')
  } else {
    ftCard.style.display = ('inline')
  }

  // height output
  document.getElementById('cmOutput').innerHTML =
    numberWithSpaces(Math.round(cm * 1000) / 1000);

  document.getElementById('mtOutput').innerHTML =
    numberWithSpaces(Math.round(cm * 2.20462262 * 1000) / 1000);

  document.getElementById('ftOutput').innerHTML =
    numberWithSpaces(Math.round(cm * 35.2739619 * 1000) / 1000);

}
//Seperate thousands by spaces
function numberWithSpaces(x) {
  return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    body {
      margin-top: 70px;
      background: #333;
      color: #fff;
    }
    
    .card {
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .card-primary {
      background: blue;
    }
    
    .card-success {
      background: green;
    }
    
    .card-danger {
      background: red;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Weight Converter</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <h1 class="display-4 text-center mb-3">Converter</h1>

        <button onclick="weightFunction()" id='weightbtn'> Weight</button>
        <button onclick="heightFunction()" id='heightbtn'> Height</button>



        <form>

          <div class="form-group">
            <input id="massInput" type="number" class="form-control form-control-lg mb-2" placeholder="Enter Weight...">


            <div id="radios">
              <div id="weightRadios">
                <input class='inputCheck' id='kgChecked' type="radio" name='unit' value='kg' checked='checked'> kg <br>

                <input class='inputCheck' id='lbsChecked' type="radio" name='unit' value='lbs' checked='checked'> lbs <br>

                <input class='inputCheck' id='ozChecked' type="radio" name='unit' value='oz' checked='checked'> oz <br>
              </div>

              <div id="heightRadios">
                <input class='inputChecked' id='cmChecked' type="radio" name='unit' value='cm' checked='checked'> cm <br>

                <input class='inputChecked' id='metersChecked' type="radio" name='unit' value='meters' checked='checked'> Mt <br>

                <input class='inputChecked' id='ftChecked' type="radio" name='unit' value='ft' checked='checked'> ft<br>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div id="weightOutput">
          <div id="lbsCard">
            <div class="card card-primary mb-2">
              <div class="card-block">
                <h4>Pounds</h4>
                <div id="lbsOutput"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div id="kgCard">
            <div class="card card-success mb-2">
              <div class="card-block">
                <h4>kilograms</h4>
                <div id="kgOutput"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="ozCard">
            <div class="card card-danger mb-2">
              <div class="card-block">
                <h4>Ounces</h4>
                <div id="ozOutput"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div id="heightOutput">
          <div id="cmCard">
            <div class="card card-primary mb-2">
              <div class="card-block">
                <h4>cm</h4>
                <div id="cmOutput"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div id="mtCard">
            <div class="card card-success mb-2">
              <div class="card-block">
                <h4>meters</h4>
                <div id="mtOutput"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="ftCard">
            <div class="card card-danger mb-2">
              <div class="card-block">
                <h4>feet</h4>
                <div id="ftOutput"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you very much. very much appreciated. I will try and optimize the code.

Comment: @Bless No worries happy to help.

Comment: helping, the answer is indeed correct and helpful, but I've just realized that now that the height side is working the weight side is not working anymore

Comment: @Bless Its all working in my answer. both height and weight! You can check. You need to debug your own code or copy my exact code to see match whats going on in your code! Also please consider accepting my answer ?

Comment: @ AlwaysHelping, I have accepted your answer and thank you very much. I'm still learning so I know there is a lot of things I miss. I'm still trying to figure out why my height cards are showing when I chose a weight radio even if I have them displayed none. without chasing a weight radio its working but assuming that we are only converting kgs. I hope I will get to the bottom of this. thanks a lot though

Comment: @Bless  Thanks you so much. Happy to help. Please refer to my answer. It should be all working in your website as well.

Comment: @Bless You need to set set all the card to `display:none` in your CSS when you load the code and then `display:block` the cards when needed.